# create a query or function to show a specific field with 'where_in' clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to show a result with some specific fields and specific id, but i dont know how to do it.

The code below is my experiment but its showing all results (not based on id)

```
$this->db->where_in('id',$id);
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT name,email,birthdate from person");
$result = $query->result_array();
```

I expect the output is a result based on the id, but the output is showing all result.. btw, the id is an array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is like:

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date')
$this->db->where('id', $id); 
$result = $this->db->get("person")->result_array();
```

Where title, content, date can be consider as specific column.

Answer (score 0):

`query` and `where_in` will not work simultaneously, here is the modified code

if you want to search using multiple ids then use `where_in`

```
$this->db->where_in('id', [$id]); // here second parameter should be array
$result = $this->db->get("person")->result_array();
```

if you want to search using single id then use `where`

```
$this->db->where('id', $id); 
$result = $this->db->get("person")->result_array();
```

Please find the reference document [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: but how if i want to just get some specific field, not all fields?

Comment: @FikriMuhamadFahmi check the answer I have specified that also